# How do I read an Excel column as datetime.datetime instead of the auto datetime.time

Tags: python

I am trying to select rows of a pandas Dataframe within a date range. The dataframe is uploaded from an Excel and the date is automatically saved as datetime.time which is causing problems when comparing to datetime.datetime.

I tried converting the datetime.time to datetime.datetime using pd.to_datetime but it didn't work, maybe because it is in a DF. I tried setting the column to datetime.datetime when it is being read. I have tried converting to datetime.datetime while being read. None of these worked. The column is named Sub_End and it is just a 5 digit number with date format, like 42636 is 9/23/2016.

Here are some of the upload attempts I have made:

```
Subadvisory_Advisor_Fires=pd.read_excel('SOLO_Advisor_Data.xlsx',sheetname='Advisor_Fires', dtype={'Sub_End': date})
```

This read the file with no issue but the column was still datetime.time

```
Subadvisory_Advisor_Fires=pd.read_excel('SOLO_Advisor_Data.xlsx',sheetname='Advisor_Fires',  converters= {'Sub_End': pd.to_datetime})
```

I got an error on this one:
TypeError:  is not convertible to datetime

```
Subadvisory_Advisor_Fires=pd.read_excel('SOLO_Advisor_Data.xlsx',sheetname='Advisor_Fires', dtype={'Sub_End': datetime.datetime})
```

This read the file with no issue but the column was still datetime.time

The code that is having the error is:

```
Advisor_Fires=Subadvisory_Advisor_Fires
Start_Datetime = datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 31)
End_Datetime = datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 31)
Advisor_Fires = Advisor_Fires[(Advisor_Fires['Sub_End']).between(Start_Datetime, End_Datetime)]
```

The error I get is:

```
TypeError: can't compare datetime.time to datetime.datetime
```

I am just trying to limit the rows to include one where they are between these two dates. Nothing I have tried has allowed the date in the Excel file to be read properly as dates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is an easier way to do this, but I got this to work

```
Subadvisory_Advisor_Fires=pd.read_excel('SOLO_Advisor_Data.xlsx',sheetname='Advisor_Fires', converters={'Sub_End':str})
Year = Subadvisory_Advisor_Fires['Sub_End'].str.slice(0, 4)
Month = Subadvisory_Advisor_Fires['Sub_End'].str.slice(5, 7)
Day = Subadvisory_Advisor_Fires['Sub_End'].str.slice(8, 10)

Year = pd.to_numeric(Year, errors='coerce')
Month = pd.to_numeric(Month, errors='coerce')
Day = pd.to_numeric(Day, errors='coerce')

Dates = pd.to_datetime((Year*10000+Month*100+Day).apply(str),format='%Y%m%d')
Subadvisory_Advisor_Fires['Sub_End_Converted'] = Dates
```